# invalid binary- invalid swift support

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I get invalid binary when I submit my application. The whole application is in swift so I tried `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` to `YES` in the target settings but yet nothing happens I still get invalid binary. What should be in the build settings? How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried every possible solution that were suggested on the Internet and the solution that worked for me is to create a new project and copy your files over.

Comment: how did you copy your files over? just drag-and-drop?

Comment: I create a new project and rename it and then drag and drop all the files over.

As for frameworks I use Cocoa Pods